# Add a try-catch construction here to catch "ArgumentNullException"

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The method should return true if an "ArgumentNullException" is thrown and set "exceptionMessage" parameter to an exception message; otherwise the method should return false.

```
public static bool CatchArgumentNullException(object obj, out string exceptionMessage)
{
    exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (obj is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return false;
 }
```

The method returns false. Why? How to return true?

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's [classification of exceptions](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/): "Boneheaded exceptions ... You should not catch them; doing so is hiding a bug in your code. Rather, you should write your code so that the exception cannot possibly happen in the first place, and therefore does not need to be caught."

Comment: ... because you only ever `return false;`? This whole thing is a bit wonky, what are you trying to do? Is this some sort of a programming excercise?

Comment: You catch the exception and don't do anything with it, so the code falls out of your tye/catch and returns false.

Comment: I have a specific task to make an exception.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exceptions can also be used to control the flow of the execution in a simple and clean way for some CPU clocks in counterpart. Sometimes it can be better than using some `if` and `boolean`... The *Flow control of the code execution by  Exception* can really be a great design. Personnally I use it a lot to write less and more robust code. Telling to not catch exception and use them is an arbitrary opinion that deprives of enormous potential.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception just for yourself in the first place? It's a very expensive operation as it creates a full stack trace and all so it must not used as a control flow unless you really must to do so. What do you want to achieve with this code? To obtain the default resource string `message = new ArgumentNullException().Message` does the trick.

Comment: @OlivierRogier - the point (if you go and read the article) is that *certain types* of exceptions shouldn't be caught. The point is, an `ArgumentNullException` is a programmer error, not something that needs to be dealt with at runtime.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But by doing this here the OP can get a standard and localized system message including the name of the variable using eg my response. At first glance, I saw no interest in the question, I wrote an answer, and see the usefulness...

Comment: @OlivierRogier: No way, it's almost never a good design. In some exceptional cases it can be justified such as signing cancellation from a deep call but it has a huge cost compared to simple `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add return in catch statement
2. You can change code as below depending if you only want to catch ArgumentNullException or all type of exceptions. Your current catch statement is for all kind of exceptions.

```
public static bool CatchArgumentNullException(object obj, out string exceptionMessage)
{
    exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (obj is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @OlivierRogier that was part of question submitted by user. Question was edited after my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Code corrected**

```
public static bool CatchArgumentNullException(object obj, out string exceptionMessage)
{
  exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
  try
  {
    if ( obj is null )
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Test**

```
object obj1 = null;
object obj2 = new object();

if ( CatchArgumentNullException(obj1, out var msg1) )
  Console.WriteLine("obj1: " + msg1);
else
  Console.WriteLine("obj1 is not null");

if ( CatchArgumentNullException(obj2, out var msg2) )
  Console.WriteLine("obj2: " + msg2);
else
  Console.WriteLine("obj2 is not null");
```

**Output**

```html
obj1: La valeur ne peut pas être null. // The value can't be null.

obj2 is not null
```

**Improvement**

```
public static bool IsArgumentNull(object instance, string name, out string errorMessage)
{
  errorMessage= string.Empty;
  try
  {
    if ( instance is null )
      throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    errorMessage= ex.Message;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```
object obj1 = null;
object obj2 = new object();

if ( IsArgumentNull(obj1, nameof(obj1), out var msg1) )
  Console.WriteLine(msg1);
else
  Console.WriteLine("obj1 is not null");

if ( IsArgumentNull(obj2, nameof(obj2), out var msg2) )
  Console.WriteLine(msg2);
else
  Console.WriteLine("obj2 is not null");
```

```html
The value can't be null.
Name of the parameter : obj1

obj2 is not null
```

*Now this is a method that returns true if an object is null and we have a standard and localized system message including the variable name.*